# How to get the latest available ID + 1 in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, insert, identity

I'm new to Oracle.

My Clients table has ID and Name columns.

ID is a NUMBER(10) and apparently Oracle doesn't support incremental identity.

How to get the latest available ID + 1 in Oracle?

```
INSERT INTO Clients (ID, Name) VALUES (?, Name)
```

we don't want to use triggers.

Comment: `we don't want to use triggers.` What prevents using sequence(s) without triggers?

Comment: How do you mean? how to use sequence?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php Use sequences as a default value for your ID

Comment: Oracle 12C will support `IDENTITY` columns - see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17906/chapter1.htm - but that doesn't help you right now.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle provides a highly scalable method to generate a number sequence by using schema objects called [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/schemaob.htm#i5667).

You create a sequence by issuing [create sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) statement. For example:

```
create sequence Seq1
start with 1         
increment by 1   
nomaxvalue;
```

Then you can access sequences' values with the `curval` or `nextval` pseudocolumns, which return current or next value generated by a sequence respectively, in a SQL statement or starting from Oracle 11g you can assign the value of a sequence directly to a variable in a PL/SQL block:

Having said that, you can use a newly created sequence in your insert statement as follows, if you do not want to use a trigger to automatically fill in you primary key column with a new value:

```
INSERT INTO Clients (id, Name) 
   VALUES (seq1.nextval, Name)
```